# Bevel not being generated on a shrinkwraped modified

Tags: bevel

I am trying to make a cutter tool out of a hiking path file through a mountain. Therefore I am using an imported GPX file, modifier of shrinkwrap on the mountain, and then have added a bevel from a plane / round.  However when I create the bevel, it appears to shrinkwrap everything (the solid) on to the mountain, so I am unable to create a cutting tool (via Boolean modifier)...any ideas on why this would be so?

[image]

Comment: I don’t understand. Are you trying to… I have no idea what you’re trying to do. A cutting tool? Is there supposed to be a tool that cuts a cross-section of mountain ranges on some thing, like a stamp roller?

Comment: yes please give some additional informations, do you have pictures of what you're trying to do?